# EntityQuery where multi-value field contains a value

Tags: entities

I've been programming for 15 years, 10 with PHP, but on my 1st Drupal project. Using Drupal 9.

I'm trying to retrieve an entity (custom content type) that has 2 multi-value entity (user) fields. If the value I have is in one field I want to get the other one. The problem is I can't figure out how to ask for the entity when the scalar value I have is in the list. Here's what I've got:

```
return \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'osj_relationships')
  ->condition('field_supervised_reps', [$userId], 'IN')
  ->execute();
```

Which generates this SQL:

```
'SELECT "base_table"."vid" AS "vid", "base_table"."nid" AS "nid"
FROM
"node" "base_table"
INNER JOIN "node_field_data" "node_field_data" ON "node_field_data"."nid" = "base_table"."nid"
INNER JOIN "node__field_supervised_reps" "node__field_supervised_reps" ON "node__field_supervised_reps"."entity_id" = "base_table"."nid"
WHERE ("node_field_data"."type" = 'osj_relationships') AND ("node__field_supervised_reps"."field_supervised_reps_target_id" IN ('2458'))'
```

The 2nd part of the WHERE clause is looking for the field value in my parameter. I need it to look for my parameter in the field. I've also tried CONTAINS but that seems to assume the field value is a string rather than an array. If I could turn that WHERE clause around it would be perfect. ie.

```
(('2458') IN "node__field_supervised_reps"."field_supervised_reps_target_id")
```

I suppose I could use 'CONTAINS' if I could implode the field list but that would risk false hits.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You don't even have to use `IN` here, only if you have multiple `$userId`s, otherwise a simple `=` operator will work:

```
return \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'osj_relationships')
  ->condition('field_supervised_reps', $userId)
  ->execute();
```

The generated query will actually work how you'd like. It works because each value of a multi-value field is stored in its own row in the database.

For example, given a multi-value entity reference field, field_tags, added to article nodes, if you have an article (with id = 111), referencing two taxonomy terms with ids 222 and 333, the `node__field_tags` table might look like:

| bundle | deleted | entity_id | revision_id | langcode | delta | field_tags_target_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| article | 0 | 111 | 777 | en | 0 | 222 |
| article | 0 | 111 | 777 | en | 1 | 333 |

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I only started messing with 'in' & 'contains' after '=' didn't work. In addition to the entityQuery(), I've also tried entityTypeManager():
    return \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('node')
      ->loadByProperties([
        'type'=>'osj_relationships',
        'field_supervised_reps'=>$userId
      ]);
...with the same result (empty array). I've verified the target I'm looking for is in the database and the field names are right. I've tried intval($userid) which also didn't change anything. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, upon closer inspection, I discovered a spelling problem when I created the content type. As always, the stupid machine is doing what it's told. 'osj_relationships' != 'osj_releationships'

Ugh.

Thanks for at least validating that I'm barking up the right tree.